# Instapy crashes instantly after login without performing any action

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, instapy

Instapy was running perfectly fine and suddenly I started to get warning Login test detected. And since then I'm unable to run it.

Here is error log-

```
    InstaPy Version: 0.6.13
     ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.
    Workspace in use: "/home/ubuntu/InstaPy"
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:38] [username]  Session started!
    oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:38] [username]  -- Connection Checklist [1/2] (Internet Connection Status)
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:39] [username]  - Internet Connection Status: ok
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:39] [username]  - Current IP is "152.64.1.152" and it's from "India/IN"
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:39] [username]  -- Connection Checklist [2/2] (Hide Selenium Extension)
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:39] [username]  - window.navigator.webdriver response: True
    WARNING [2021-05-09 18:10:39] [username]  - Hide Selenium Extension: error
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:10:45] [username]  - Cookie file not found, creating cookie...
    WARNING [2021-05-09 18:10:50] [username]  Login A/B test detected! Trying another string...
    WARNING [2021-05-09 18:10:55] [username]  Could not pass the login A/B test. Trying last string...
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:11:13] [username]  - Do not save Login Info by now...
    .......................................................................................................................
    CRITICAL [2021-05-09 18:11:27] [username]  Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    INFO [2021-05-09 18:11:29] [username]  Sessional Live Report:
            |> No any statistics to show


    [Session lasted 1.01 minutes]
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
    INFO [2021-05-09 18:11:29] [username]  Session ended!
    oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

You can see it's is able to login but instantly kills the session, people suggest it's due to some sort of loop.

I checked login_util.py but can't find something useful. I think it's probably due to some changes in Instagram's homepage after login to tackle suspicious accounts. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue? if yes, other users might profit from your solution. please share, this is what stackoverflow is for!

Comment: Sorry i didn't find any solution & have to finally quit.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72190566/14457833) may help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are no errors in the code after you start the session.
If an exception occurs and the program exits, you will also see `No any statistics to show`.

The easiest way to test this is to run `quickstart.py`.
https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/blob/master/quickstart.py