# instapy doesn't login into account

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instapy

I'm trying to use instapy but I keep getting this error

```
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:14] []  -- Connection Checklist [1/2] (Internet Connection Status)
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:16] []  - Internet Connection Status: ok
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:16] []  -- Connection Checklist [2/2] (Instagram Server Status)
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:24] []  - Instagram WebSite Status: Currently Up 
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:24] []  - Instagram Response Time: 108.423 ms 
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:24] []  - Instagram Reponse Code: 200
INFO [2021-08-02 19:24:24] []  - Instagram Server Status: ok
Cookie file not found, creating cookie...
Login A/B test detected! Trying another string...

............................................................................................................................
CRITICAL [2021-08-02 19:24:43] []  Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

I install it with pip and pip3 and it doesn't work at all
It stoped when instagram asked to accept cookies

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: Which version of `instapy` are you using?

Comment: @blackbrandt   I'm using instapy-0.5.8

Answer (score 3):

Calling the class initializer with parameter `want_check_browser=False` worked for me as following:

```
session = InstaPy(username="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD", headless_browser=False, want_check_browser=False)
```

However, it seems like a workaround.

Also, you can check `login_util.py` line 246 in version 0.6.16, it says,

> ```
> # Hotfix - this check crashes more often than not -- plus in not necessary,
> # I can verify my own connection
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In `xpath_compile.py`:

Line 159 ```` "login_elem_no_such_exception": "//a[text()='Log``` In']", ````

It needs to look like this

Line 159 `"login_elem_no_such_exception": "//button[text()='Log In']",`

You can find the file:

- on Linux: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/instapy`
- on Windows: `E:\Users\(yourprofile)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\instapy`

Source: https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/4877#issuecomment-522282119