# InstaPy - Unable to Login Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, geckodriver, instapy

When i run my script getting this error

```sh
CRITICAL [2022-05-17 20:02:33] [my_user]  Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above.
```

InstaPy not connecting anymore.

I changed all the ways below:

1. I changed to my geckodriver place into the `/usr/bin/geckodriver` but still same
2. I copied geckodriver into the workspace and gave direct path with `browser_executable_path = {filepath}`
3. I tried with changing `headless_browser` option into the `True`
4. I tried with changing `headless_browser` option into the `False`

Here is my code:

```py
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
from user_data import my_username, my_password


session = InstaPy(username = my_username, 
                  password = my_password,
                  headless_browser = False,
                 
        )

session.login()


with smart_run(session):
    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled = True,
                                    delimit_by_numbers=True,
                                    max_followers=500,
                                    min_followers=50)
    
    session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=100)
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72190566/14457833)